# apt-get update does not work in my terminal I get an no route to host error

Tags: kali-linux

```
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113). - connect (113: No route to host)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to check ip tables and turning on apache2 this doesn't help.

`apt-get update` does not work in my terminal; I get a `no route to host` error. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade

Comment: `ip tables` isn't a valid command. Did you perhaps mean `iptables` or `ip addr show`?

Comment: Why should turning on apache2 help? Look at the error message "_No route to host_". It means what it says: that there is no network route from your machine to the target address

Comment: sorry I mean iptables. I read in an article that turning on apache2 might help, but it does not. My internet connection is working. I also tried it as sudo and turned of kali and turned it on. I do run it in vmware I don't know if this has anything to do with te problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the problem

Have you checked your internet connection ???

Is the problem also popping on apt-get update ?????

Also try execute it as sudo

And if not restart your computer

Comment: I did a ping to my router and to google they both worked. I also executed it as sudo, and also tried to turn kali on and of. I added extra links in /etc/apt/sources.list, and did everything on this site https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade. ps I am running this in vmware, I dont know if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the fix is to restart kali as a normal start, this way you have to type in your user and pass to get on kali again should fix this problem.