# Kali linux “sudo apt-get update” freezes

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I have kali linux installed on my mac. `apt-get` worked fine until 2 weeks ago. I didn't change any configs but regardless of what i do e.g. run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it just freezes. I have no clue how to debug this and could really use some guidance.

This is my version:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2020.4"
VERSION_ID="2020.4"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` it freezes without any execution. I've looked at some of the similar questions but it seems all of them have some sort of response after the command.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade

Comment: You could use `strace` to understand what the process is doing.

Comment: Can you define 'freezes'?  When you type `sudo apt-get update`, is anything printed to stdout at all?  If you don't even get a `[sudo] password for lukas:` then this could be a problem with authentication.